# How do I turn off "smart" multiple selection? (3ds Max UI preset)

Tags: selection-tools

I'm not sure if this is something to do with the preset or a default setting that I can't find the switch for. I'm trying to finally learn Blender after years of 3ds Max and I was extremely glad that it now ships with the Max and Maya style UI options. In edit mode, when I CTRL-Click to select multiple objects, Blender will try to automatically select any points in between the two I select, unless I go back, unselect the auto-selected point and try selecting again. And if there's multiple points between my two selection points, forget it. I see where this could be a useful feature but not as a default, so how do I turn it off?

Comment: This is what blender does by default normally, not sure about the 3Ds max preset. With default blender Shift + RMB selects individual vertices

Answer (score 2):

gandalf, that got me pointed in the right direction. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> does it in the Max preset.